# ORA-01722: invalid number when using to_number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the max project code in a table using project codes and a customer code like so

```
SELECT DISTINCT       Max(to_number(translate(substr(proj_code,7),'0123456789','0123456789')))
    FROM
        proj_ca
    WHERE
        proj_code LIKE 'CUST43_%'
        AND cust_code = 'CUST';
```

This code is supposed to return 97
When I run this code i get ORA-01722 invalid number, however when I do 42 or 44 it returns the proper number. I'm not sure why the "to_number" is throwing an error.

I have narrowed it down to the "to_number" part. If I remove that it returns 97 without any issues.

Comment: Do you have rows for CUST4397 with code CUST and something else; but the other ones you can get successfully *only* have CUST? Or other things that start with `CUST4397` but sort before it - i.e. what do you see without the max?

Comment: What is `translate` supposed to do? The way you wrote it, it does absolutely nothing. I imagine you think it does something, and perhaps that's the issue (or one issue, anyway).

Comment: what version of Oracle are you on? I ask because in 12.2, [`to_number` has been extended](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) so it can handle conversion errors much better.

Comment: @AlexPoole all the project codes have numbers after. So all the rows contain CUSTXXXX. Without max it returns all the rows that contain CUST43XX.

Comment: @mathguy I didn't write the code. Can you explain why it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Boneist we are on version 12.1 unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's `TRANSLATE` function will not do anything to characters that are in the input string but not in the list of characters to translate from.  So this:

```
select translate(substr('CUST4397B',7),'0123456789','0123456789') 
from dual;
```

will return "97B", not "97".

Try putting this into your code instead:

```
select regexp_replace(substr('CUST4397B',7),'[^0-9]','')  answer
from dual;
```

> ```
> answer
> ------
> 97
> ```

Comment: The underscore is a single wildcard in the `like`; so I don't see (from the question text, which refers to it returning 97 otherwise) that there is a literal underscore to deal with? It's a bit confused though...

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, of course.  I quickly read it as a literal underscore, because, if it were not, I would have expected `LIKE 'CUST43%'.  Maybe she's trying to make sure there is at least one position after the 43.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I did not write that code so I am assuming @MatthewMcPeak that you're theory is correct on the position. Will this code convert the string to a number? Or do I need to add 
```select max(to_number(regexp_replace(substr('CUST4397B',7),'[^0-9]','')))```

Comment: Yes, you still need the `max(to_number(..))`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Matthew this worked! Looking through the list there was a project code with an 'A' at the end. However there had been many projects made after that so I was sure it wasn't the problem. Guess it was after all. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach which is, I think, a bit more flexible would be to use

```
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PROJ_CODE, '[0-9]{2}', 1, 2)))
  FROM PROJ_CA
  WHERE PROJ_CODE LIKE 'CUST43%' AND
        CUST_CODE = 'CUST'
```

Here the position of the numbers within the string are not hardcoded - instead, the second group of two digits found in the string is extracted, which is the case of `CUST4397B` is `97`.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c922a6e7b21e5b0073057bdbc3e98f90)

Comment: I like it.  But this version trades one assumption (starting at 7th position) with another (project numbers are always 2 positions).  If we're going for maximum flexibility, how about `REGEXP_SUBSTR(proj_code, '43([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)`?

Comment: In a comment OP said "...all the project codes have numbers after. So all the rows contain CUSTXXXX...". But, in my defense, this will still work for project numbers like VENDORXXXX or COWHERDERXXXX or WHATINHECKISTHISSUPPOSEDTOBEXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the input was CUST43_42 translate is going to return the output as '_42' which cannot be converted to a number, hence to_number throws invalid number.
Try SUBSTR (proj_code, 8)

Comment: The input is always going to be customer code and two numbers after so it will always be CUSTXX. Does that make sense? However I did try your suggestion and got the same error

Comment: is it possible for you to share a sample data